# How to integrate calendar module with structure module

Tags: structure, calendar

We have setup calendar module and create calendar template (as below) but when i click on previous or next month rise an error "404 page not found"

Note: I'm using structure module to generate pages and navigation

```
 {exp:calendar:events limit="1"}<h1 class="page-title">{calendar_title}</h1>{/exp:calendar:events}
{exp:calendar:cal 
    enable="custom_fields" 
    pad_short_weeks="y"
    show_weeks="4" 
    date_range_start="{embed:embeded_date}-01" date_range_end="{embed:embeded_date}-last"
    category="{embed:cat}"
    dynamic="no"
    parse="inward"
    status="not closed"
}
 {display_each_month}


<div class="event-cal clearfix">
<ul class="calendar-nav">
<li class="current-month">{date format="%F %Y"}</li>
<li class="prev-month"><a href="{structure:page:url}{prev_month format="%Y/%m"}">
                               Previous
                            </a></li>
<li class="next-month"><a href="{structure:page:url}{next_month format="%Y/%m"}/">
                                Next
                            </a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="days-of-week">
    {display_each_day_of_week}
        <div class="cal-day">{day_of_week_short}</div>
        {/display_each_day_of_week}
</div>
    {display_each_week}
<div class="cal-week">
        {display_each_day}
        <div class="cal-date">

{if day_event_total !="0"} 
                    <a href="#" data-options="align:right" data-dropdown="drop-{date format="%F-%d"}" class="button">{date format="%d"}</a>
                    <div id="drop-{date format="%F-%d"}" class="event-tooltip small content f-dropdown"  data-dropdown-content>
                    <h4>{date format="%F %d, %Y"}</h4>
                    <ul>
                    {events}
                        <li><a href="{page_url}">› {event_title}</a></li>
                    {/events}
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    {if:else}
                   <span class="no-event">{date format="%d"}</span>
        {/if}


        </div>   
        {/display_each_day}
</div>
    {/display_each_week}

</div>
{/display_each_month}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Structure's developers you need to have the calendar tag in a non-Structure managed template for pagination to work.

https://structure.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/1337-conflict-with-solspace-calendar-pagination-and-structure-3-attempting-to-find-workaround#comment_9835986